# Can you use the word “cochonnerie” as nonsense?

Tags: vocabulaire, registre-familier

I know that this is used for junk food, but can you also say “Il dit des cochonneries ?” as in what he's saying is total nonsense?  or is there another translation or is it simply not used in with *parler* or *dire*...?

Comment: I won't add an answer, the previous ones are great. I will just add two correct expressions that can replace your expression: *il dit des bêtises* and *il dit des sottises*.

Answer (score 11):

**About the use of "cochonneries"**

In my experience *(I'm from Quebec, Canada)* :

> Il mange des cochonneries

is used to expression someone eating junk food.

> Il dit des cochonneries.

is not used to express nonsense, but is used for sexual related stuff. This can also be used with the verbe "faire" to express the action, instead of just talking about it.

So, people might *(and probably will)* misinterpret you if you use it to describe nonsense. And that could get you to some awkward situations!

---

**What would be a correct expression**

As far as I'm thinking I don't really see any expression to tell people that what they say makes no sense but something like

> Ça n'a aucun sens ce que tu dis!

Which is very litteral.

Actually, there would be a very "street-y" expression to mean nonsense :

> Tu dis de la merde!

Comment: Your description of the usage of *cochonneries* also applies to France.

Comment: I agree with Gilles. But "tu dis de la merde" is definitely from Quebec. Here the common expression is "tu dis des conneries" (slang) or "tu dis des bêtises".

Comment: @Gurney: It applies to France as well. I guess you are not “street-y” enough :-)

Answer (score 10):

Cochonneries describe multiple things in the french language:

1. junk food
2. trash, rubbish, dirty objects and things
3. sexual activity, as in *faire des cochonneries*
4. dirty talk, as in *dire des cochonneries*

Answer (score 4):

Make *cochonnerie* a bit shorter, and you can use it :)

> Tu ne dis que des conneries

If you want to use the verb *parler*, you could use the following expression

> Tu parles pour ne rien dire

Answer (score 1):

On top of Hugo Dozois's answer, I would translate *what he's saying is total nonsense* as follows:

Formal:

> - Ce qu'il dit est dénué de sens. *(this one is really formal)*
> - Ce qu'il dit n'a aucun sens.
> - Ce qu'il dit n'a pas de sens.

Unformal:

> - Il dit n'importe quoi.

Derogatory/colloquial:

> - Il dit des conneries.
> - Il dit de la merde. *(this one is worse than the previous one)*